# Passport.js middleware redirect not working with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, passport.js

I'm sending some data from JS to Node via AJAX and JQuery. I've set up a post request in Node, and I've included a middleware to check if the user is logged in (and reroute them to log in page if not).

The res.redirect() in my middleware, however, doesn't seem to work with my AJAX post request. I set up another GET route with the middleware and it worked fine, it just doesn't like AJAX for some reason. Here's my code:

AJAX POST request from JS:

```
saveButton.on("click", function() {
   var mealPlan = [];
   var inputText = $(".saveInput").val();
   mealPlan.push(breakfastArr);
   mealPlan.push(lunchArr);
   mealPlan.push(dinnerArr);
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      data: {plan: mealPlan, name: inputText},
      url: "/saverecipe"
   })
   .done(function() {
      console.log("Done");
   })
   .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   })
});
```

Route:

```
app.post("/saverecipe", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    //find the user
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //create the meal plan
            Plan.create(req.body, function(err, plan) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //push meal plan into user
                    user.mealPlans.push(plan);
                    user.save();
                    console.log("saved.");
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Middleware:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        console.log("Must log in");
        res.redirect("/login");
        req.flash("error", "Please log in first.");
    }
};
```

If I'm not logged in, it seems that the middleware works minus the res.redirect() bit. The console.log("Must log in") inside isLoggedIn runs, and the console.log("saved.") inside the app.post does not run, indicating that the function didn't complete. The only thing not working is the res.redirect(). Not sure why.

Any help you can give is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using AJAX. The HTTP Response should be handled in the callback. That's means you should check the return from server and make the redirection on your own.

Here is a simple example for AJAX handle the Redirection HTTP Response Code.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  data: {plan: mealPlan, name: inputText},
  url: "/saverecipe"
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  // Get the HTTP Response Code
  let statusCode = jqXHR.status
  // Check if it is equal to 301 
  if( Number(statusCode) === 301 ) {
    // Handle Redirection
    // Retrive Location Header
    let location = jqXHR.getResponseHeader( 'Location' )
    // If Location Header is found. Start Redirection
    if( location ) window.location.replace( location )
  }
  console.log('Done')
})
.fail(function(err){
  console.log(err)
})
```

More information on using AJAX, you can refer to the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/